# Code to run only when there's a new entry and not to duplicate previous entries

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to app script editing and have been following instructions to create a script to generate certificates - I only want the script to run if there's a new entry on the list and would like this to run autmatically when a new entry is added. I believe I need an IF function but not confident using these yet - any help is much appreciated!

```
let slideTemplateId = "1pS1ZQfhqY9QyIbTbXFdx5u_bZAnw67ekut2hmGf0aDk";
let tempFolderId = "1hYiZNe9w-1EERVCPT0bZDW8h52HmsRDm"; // Create an empty folder in Google Drive

    /**
 * Creates a custom menu "Appreciation" in the spreadsheet
 * with drop-down options to create and send certificates
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Post-Training Certificates')
  .addItem('Create certificates', 'createCertificates')
  .addSeparator()
  .addItem('Send certificates', 'sendCertificates')
  .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Creates a personalized certificate for each employee
 * and stores every individual Slides doc on Google Drive
 */
function createCertificates() {
  
  // Load the Google Slide template file
  let template = DriveApp.getFileById(slideTemplateId);
  
  // Get all employee data from the spreadsheet and identify the headers
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Certificates');
  let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let headers = values[0];
  let nameIndex = headers.indexOf("Name");
  let dateIndex = headers.indexOf("Date");
  let courseIndex = headers.indexOf("Course");
  let employeeEmailIndex = headers.indexOf("Employee Email");


  // Iterate through each row to capture individual details
  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    let rowData = values[i];
    let name = rowData[nameIndex];
    let date = rowData[dateIndex];
    let course = rowData[courseIndex];
    let employeeEmail = rowData[employeeEmailIndex];
    
    // Make a copy of the Slide template and rename it with employee name
    let tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(tempFolderId);
    let empSlideId = template.makeCopy(tempFolder).setName(name).getId();        
    let empSlide = SlidesApp.openById(empSlideId).getSlides()[0];
    
    // Replace placeholder values with actual employee related details
    empSlide.replaceAllText("<<Name>>", name);
    empSlide.replaceAllText("<<Date>>", Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMM dd, yyyy"));
    empSlide.replaceAllText("<<Course>>", course);

    
    // Update the spreadsheet with the new Slide Id and status
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).setValue(empSlideId);
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 6).setValue("CREATED");
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: By new entry  - do you mean a new row with data? Whene exactly is an entry considered complete and the caode shall run ru automaticaly? After both `name`, `date`, `course` and `employeeEmail` in a row are not empty?

Comment: Yes, when there's a new row of data - probably triggered by at least name.

Comment: It's important to know what triggers the last row, I will provide you a solution triggered by the last name - if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

### Use an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to both run the code automatically on edit and only on the newest entry

- The `onEdit` trigger will run each time a human edit has been made on the spreadsheet. You will further need a [conditional statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) to specify that your request shall only be exectued if the edit took place in a certain column of a certain sheet
- The `onEdit` trigger gives you an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) that gives you information about the event, such as which cell has been edited
- The `installable` part is important because toherwise the code will run into authorization problems when accessing a folder on your Drive. Please read the documentaiton linked abpove regarding further explanation and instructions how to set up an installable trigger

Sample:

```js
let slideTemplateId = "1pS1ZQfhqY9QyIbTbXFdx5u_bZAnw67ekut2hmGf0aDk";
let tempFolderId = "1hYiZNe9w-1EERVCPT0bZDW8h52HmsRDm"; // Create an empty folder in Google Drive


/**
 * Runs onEdit after you bind it to an installable onEdit trigger correctly
 */
function createCertificates(event) {

 var sheetName = event.range.getSheet().getName();
// RUN THE REST OF THE CODE ONLY IF A CERTAIN SHEET HAS BEEN EDITED
 if(sheetName == "Certificates"){
  
  // Load the Google Slide template file
  let template = DriveApp.getFileById(slideTemplateId);
  
  // Get all employee data from the spreadsheet and identify the headers
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Certificates');
  let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let headers = values[0];
  let nameIndex = headers.indexOf("Name");
  
  let editedColumn = event.range.getColumn();
// RUN THE REST OF THE CODE ONLY IF A CERTAIN COLUMN HAS BEEN EDITED
 if(editedColumn == (nameIndex + 1 )){

  let dateIndex = headers.indexOf("Date");
  let courseIndex = headers.indexOf("Course");
  let employeeEmailIndex = headers.indexOf("Employee Email");


  // NO NEED TO ITEREATE, GET THE EDITED ROW INSTEAD
    let row = event.range.getRow();
    let rowData = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
    let name = rowData[nameIndex];
    let date = rowData[dateIndex];
    let course = rowData[courseIndex];
    let employeeEmail = rowData[employeeEmailIndex];
    
    // Make a copy of the Slide template and rename it with employee name
    let tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(tempFolderId);
    let empSlideId = template.makeCopy(tempFolder).setName(name).getId();        
    let empSlide = SlidesApp.openById(empSlideId).getSlides()[0];
    
    // Replace placeholder values with actual employee related details
    empSlide.replaceAllText("<<Name>>", name);
    empSlide.replaceAllText("<<Date>>", Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMM dd, yyyy"));
    empSlide.replaceAllText("<<Course>>", course);

    
    // Update the spreadsheet with the new Slide Id and status
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).setValue(empSlideId);
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 6).setValue("CREATED");

 }
}
```

- Please study the sample above carefully to understand the modifications and further adapt them to your needs if necessary.
- For understanding of the individual Apps SCript methods applied - please consult the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm find that at this point: let editedColumn = event.range.getColumn(); is creating an error - we're making let editedColumn into a variable? Where does it take the event.range from? I have tried to work it out!

Comment: `event.range` is the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) that becomes available when your funciton is fired on an onEdit trigger. Since the `event` object is not defined when no edit event takes place, the function `createCertificates(event)` will give you and error if you try to run it manually. It will only work automatically if it is called by the trigger (which you need to set up) whenever an edit event takes place.